# Python list different directory without chdir

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

I have a directory with my .py file and I have another directory where I am writing files to. How can I get a os.listdir of the second directory without using os.chdir?

Edit: Sorry seems like there are 2 parts to my implementation. My current code is this:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(2nd_d) if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

It currently returns an empty list when there are some files in the directory.

Comment: If you are able to use glob, I like to use that. `Fls = glob.glob(file_path)`.

Comment: Answer, since question got closed: 
make references for both inputs

```files = [f for f in os.listdir(2nd_d) if os.path.isfile(2nd_d+'/'+f)]```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the full path of that other directory.

```
dir1_contents = os.listdir('C://path/to/my/dir1')
dir2_contents = os.listdir('C://path/to/my/dir2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do a full path check?

```
import numpy as np
import os

base = 'C:/Users/user/desktop/files/'
for i in range(50):
    temp = np.random.normal(0, 1, (100, 100))
    np.save(f'{base}File_{i}.npy', temp)

files = os.listdir(base)
```